# pyodbc to Sage ERP MAS 200 Driver Error

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect to an ERP database (Sage ERP MAS 200).

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver};DSN=SOTAMAS90;autocommit=True;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Company=myCompany')
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('S1C00', '[S1C00] [ProvideX][ODBC Driver]Driver not capable (1010)(SQLSetConnnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))')
```

As you can see, I've already added "autocommit=True" as was suggested in [this FAQ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/FAQs.wiki#Connecting_fails_with_an_error_about_SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT), yet I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that "autocommit=True" must be placed outside of the connection string:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver};DSN=SOTAMAS90;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Company=myCompany',autocommit=True)
```